# Button and imageview do not work in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, button, imageview

Ok I have a problem, when the button is pressed it is supposed to take a random image from the link and display it in imageView and in my main_activity the code works, then I pass it to the snippet to use in the navigation drawer and it does not It works, I press the button and it does nothing

My code

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        var bnextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton) as Button
        var memeRandom = view.findViewById(R.id.memeRandomView) as ImageView
        bnextButton.setOnClickListener { view ->

            // val rnds = (0..99999).random()
            val quest1 = "https://proxxcraft.com/"
            // var randomGetNumber = quest1 + rnds
            Picasso.get().load(quest1).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(memeRandom)
            Picasso.get().isLoggingEnabled = true

        }
        return view
    }
```

My layaout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/memeRandomView"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memeRandomView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like the views are not accessible or button is not listening to any user action. Please try to share navigation part of code. Visually can you see button press is working? Is this the first destination in the navigation graph?

Comment: Thanks for answering but I already solved it, it was the problem `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` but it is already working